# PORTAL_NO_ACCESS and Community Plus license

Tags: community, licenses, digital-experience

- I've enabled digital experience in my org
- I've created a digital experience in my org
- I have Customer Community Plus licenses, but no Customer Community licenses in my org
- I've assigned a custom Community Plus profile to the digital experience
- I've added Role to my admin user, created Account, Contact records
- I've enabled "Allow users to self-register"

Yet, when I try to create a community user either through self-registration or apex code - I get the same error: PORTAL_NO_ACCESS.

Similarly, a Contact record has no button to manually enable it as a Community user and the "Manage External User" configuration is missing from the profile settings.

My best guess is that Salesforce *somehow* requires the org to have at least one regular Community license, before it detects that there's indeed a digital experience in the org.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a one-time salesforce issue. Once we got the Customer Community Licenses in addition to our Customer Community Plus licenses the community started working without any additional configurations.

Later we tried to replicate this bug with the Salesforce support but it appears to be some kind of a phantom bug.

Answer (score 3):

Just had to create this list for colleagues the other day, so here are all the steps to set up a Community/Portal. Based on my reading of what you've done, it looks like maybe you need to Activate the Community.

1. Setup -> Users-> Roles and click Add Role under top level and choose name like Admin and Save
2. Setup -> Users -> Users -> Edit next to your preferred System Administrator User, choose just created Role, and Save
3. Setup -> Users - User Management Settings and enable Enhanced Profile User Interface (not absolutely necessary, but makes Profile updates easier)
4. Setup -> Users -> Profiles and click Clone next to desired Profile (e.g. Customer Community Login User) (fyi likely necessary since can't update Standard Profiles and your org probably has custom objects and/or fields)
5. If created new Profile, choose Profile Name like Customer Community Login User 1 and Save
6. If created new Profile, add Create, Read, Edit object permissions to relevant objects and fields
7. Setup -> Digital Experiences -> Settings -> Enable Digital Experiences = true and choose generic Domain Name and Save
8. You’ll be redirected (probably with alert with link) to Setup -> Digital Experiences -> All Sites
9. Click New and choose your template
10. Click Get Started, choose whatever Name, and then click Create. Wait for Portal to be created
11. Click Builder. Here you can drag and drop whatever you want. Then click Publish to make changes live
12. Click Administration
13. Go to Settings and click Activate
14. Go to Members and under Select Profiles, choose Customer dropdown, and add created Profile to Selected Profiles and Save
15. Go to Page Layouts on Contact and choose Contact Page Layout
16. Go to Mobile & Lightning Actions and drag Enable Customer User and Log in to Experience as User to Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions
17. To create Community User for a Contact, make sure the Contact has an email, has Account Name/Account set, and then click the Enable Portal User button and fill out the User and Save
18. To log in as that Contact, click the Log in to Experience button on the Contact

If anyone has any suggestions or updates to this list, please let me know, and I'll update it!

Comment: Hi, @benjamin-luehrs thank you for your answer! I've carefully followed all the steps you've mentioned and everything goes smoothly until step 16. Enable Customer User and Log in to Experience are missing from available actions. I've configured identical communities on other orgs, which had both Customer Community and Customer Community Plus licenses, and the org I'm having problems with has only a Customer Community Plus license.

Comment: @OleksiiFisher Sorry to hear. I'm stumped too. As I'm sure you've looked at, Salesforce Support says the following: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338375&type=1. If still can't figure it out, I'd suggest opening a Case with Salesforce. They take forever to be resolved, but eventually you'll get someone that can help.

Comment: yeah, I've looked at this doc. Sadly, it didn't help. We are considering opening a Case but before that, I want to be 100% sure that I've tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread but does anyone know what the original poster meant by, 'I've added "Role" to my admin user?'

I note the page at help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338375&type=1 says among other things, "Ensure 'Edit' access on the Account record is given to the user for them to see 'Login to Experience as User.'"

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/202918)